# Cannot convert value of type [org.springframework.core.env.StandardEnvironment] to required type

Tags: spring

I try to upgrade spring from 3.0 to 3.2.8, but I receive the following error

Cannot convert value of type [org.springframework.core.env.StandardEnvironment] to required type [xxx] for property 'environment': no matching editors or conversion strategy found

I guess its some name conflict to an new class StandardEnvironment, but I don't find any place that defines the property 'environment'

Any help please?

Comment: Would be better, if you show the StackTrace on the matter

Comment: this is the basically the cause I get

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [org.springframework.core.env.StandardEnvironment] to required type [xxx.BackOfficeEnvironment] for property 'environment': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
 at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterDelegate.java:267)
 at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.convertIfNecessary(BeanWrapperImpl.java:448)
 ... 63 more

xxx.BackofficeEnvironment is my own class

Comment: There is need to see which class is affected. Looks like you have somewhere `environment` and injection strategy by name. But that property isn't an `org.springframework.core.env.Environment`

Comment: Show the class with `BackofficeEnvironment environment;` property

Comment: I only have a List<BackOfficeEnvironment> environments, Otherwise BackOfficeEnvironment environment are just variables in functions

Comment: @user2412555 if you don't provide the resources needed for investigation, how do you expect SO users to help you?

Comment: My problem is I don't even know what resource to provide, its a really large system, and no class actually had definition to declare the BackOfficeEnvironment environment property, I try actually to find anything in the code, just can't :(

Comment: That's why I suggest to show more StakcTrace. `to required type [xxx.BackOfficeEnvironment] for property 'environment': ` on which class? The StackTrace should show it.

Comment: This is the entire stack trace, it really doesn't help a lot it seems

Comment: If you have any autowired beans/properties named `environment` or `environments`, try changing their names.

Comment: that is the problem, I don't have an autowire on any property named "environment" or "environments" ... but I do have a default-autowire="byName" om the context.xml,

Comment: Clearly Spring thinks there is a property somewhere named `environment` that it needs to inject - thus the message in the root exception (as @ArtemBilan has been pointing out). You need to find this and then figure out how to fix it. I would suggest either a name change or use of `@Qualifier`.

Comment: yes, I just need to find it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that I have a function called setEnvironment which is in conflict with some spring builtin function setEnvironment which is used to set StandardEnvironment when initialize spring framework, so I changed function name to something else, so it worked. really weird problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your issue:

> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'backOfficeContext' defined in class path resource [se/softronic/appia/cache/DomainSpecificEhCacheBeanPostProcessorTest-context.xml]:

The class for bean 'backOfficeContext' contains property `BackOfficeEnvironment environment`

So, just change the `environment` property name to something another, or get rid of `default-autowire="byName"` and just rely on `byType` by default.

Comment: I wish I can do this, but there is no variable called environment in backOfficeContext, and I can't set to byType because it causes a lot other problems ... weird, I must look more into the code. Thanks for the help!!

Comment: I went to such extend replaced any occurrence of environment to something else, the error still occurs.